# Default value in POJO field incase of data type mismatch during JSON deserialization

Tags: java, json, java-8

When we deserialize JSON into POJO, JACKSON throws a Mismatch Input exception in case of data type mismatch, which is expected. 
So my question is, **"Is there any feature flag available in Jackson or Gson, to set the default value for mismatched field during deserialization?"**

I understand that we can implement the custom deserializer for such fields, where random input value can be expected. 
**But is this already supported using some flag in any serialization deserialization java library?**

Sample Code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.Data;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonSample {
@Data
static class Address {
    String houseAddress;
}

@Data
static class InnerJsonClass {
    Integer integerField;
    Address address;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonInput = "{\"integerField\": 1,\"address\":\"hello\"}";
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InnerJsonClass object = objectMapper.readValue(jsonInput, InnerJsonClass.class);
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**Exception:**

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.**MismatchedInputException**: Cannot construct instance of `com.paytm.logistics.JsonSample$Address` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('hello')
 at [Source: (String)"{"integerField": 1,"address":"hello"}"; line: 1, column: 30] (through reference chain: com.paytm.logistics.JsonSample$InnerJsonClass["address"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1031)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1366)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2992)
    at com.paytm.logistics.JsonSample.main(JsonSample.java:25)

Comment: I'm not sure this exists but you could try to set the default value in the POJO's constructor/initializer so that if Jackson doesn't set that value you get the default. Then you'd need to tell the parser to ignore properties that don't match - I'm not sure there's such a feature in Jackson or any other library though.

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to provide a custom yet generic deserializer, i.e. one that delegates to the standard deserializers but handles the exceptions. If that's possible (it's just an idea and I'm not able to verify it atm) you should be able to provide information on the default value via some custom annotation as well.

Comment: @Thomas, Yes, that will be the next step, which is implementing my own generic custom deserializer.

Comment: A third thing you could try might be to use `@JsonTypeInfo` along with a custom resolver. That way you might able to tell Jackson that you could either have an `Address` or a `String` and in the latter case "resolve" the string to some default value or an address with the string parsed as `houseAddress` - again the disclaimer: that's just an idea and would need to be tested or verified.

Comment: @Thomas, I will try and get back on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Address is a object, not a String.

```
String jsonInput = "{\"integerField\": 1,\"address\":{\"houseAddress\": \"hello\"}}";
```

Try this

Comment: You missed the point: the OP wants to handle the case where the caller supplies a string instead of an object, i.e. use a default address or null then.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsoninput is not in correct format it should be like below:
objectMapper will only convert value in specified object when json and pojo declaration mapping are same.

```
 String jsonInput = "{\"integerField\": 1,\"address\":{\"houseAddress\": \"hello\"}}";
```

or if you don't want to change string json then you have to use code like below

```
 @Data
    static class InnerJsonClass {
        Integer integerField;
        String address;
    }
```

Comment: You missed the point: the OP wants to handle the case where the caller supplies a string instead of an object, i.e. use a default address or null then.